# CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER set to true doesnt work on hosting server

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to process result from `$data = curl_exec($ch);` instead of printing it on the screen. In order to achieve that I set the option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true` like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```

On my local server this works as expected but when I put the same file online on my server it doesn't work.

When I set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `false` it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you just ran out of (allowed) memory on the hosting server.
When CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is set to true the whole fetched content is held in memory when set to false you only have the unechoed buffer in memory.
To verify just try to fetch something very small.

Answer (score 26):

If you set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true` or `1` then the return value from `curl_exec` will be the actual result from the successful operation. In other words it will not return `TRUE` on success. Although it will return `FALSE` on failure.

As described in the Return Values section of `curl-exec` PHP manual page: http://php.net/manual/function.curl-exec.php

You should enable the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option for redirects but this would be a problem if your server is in `safe_mode` and/or `open_basedir` is in effect which can cause issues with curl as well.

Comment: maybe I put the question wrongly. I want the result to be returned in the variable. So I set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true and it should do that but it doesnt on hosting server but on localhost it works fine. maybe some settings in php ini are not set i dont know.

Comment: @MarcelGentSimonis I edited my answer, check what safe_mode and  open_basedir are set. Your local machine probably has them disabled

Comment: Note that if not set to true the return from curl will be outputted as part of **your** response. toke an hour from me to realize that the strange output at the top of the page is because curl outputted it's response.

Comment: Just to add that "safe_mode" is eliminated since php version 5.4.0 If your server php version is higher you dont have to worry about this

Answer (score 1):

If it works fine on your local environment, probably your remote server's IP is being blocked by the server at the target URL you've set for cURL to use.
You need to *verify that your remote server is allowed to access the URL you've set for **CURLOPT_URL***.