# 23andMe API authentication via PHP

Tags: php, php-curl, 23andme-api

I am following the 23andMe [API authentication guidelines](https://api.23andme.com/docs/authentication/) and sending my users to 23andMe for authentication and authorization using this code:

```
<?php

function base64url_encode($data)
{
 $b64 = base64_encode($data);
 if ($b64 === false) {
   return false;
 }
 $url = strtr($b64, '+/', '-_');
 return rtrim($url, '=');
}

$client_id    = 'xxx';
$redirect_uri = 'https://customURL';

// this is needed for custom redirect scheme
$code_verifier = 'yyy';
$hash = hash('sha256', $code_verifier);
$code_challenge = base64url_encode(pack('H*', $hash));

header("Location: https://api.23andme.com/authorize/"
    . "?redirect_uri=$redirect_uri"
    . "&response_type=code"
    . "&client_id=$client_id"
    . "&scope=basic"
    . "&code_challenge=$code_challenge");
?>
```

Using Chrome DevTools I can see the following 3 URLs are fetched once the above page is visited, and the user authorizes the access:

```
https://auth.23andme.com/authorize/?scope=openid&response_type=code&client_id=api&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.23andme.com%2Foauth_callback%2F

https://api.23andme.com/oauth_callback/?code=30edd45deb5f42d4bb7bd8413866cfc5&state=

https://api.23andme.com/authorize/?response_type=code&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=https://customURL&scope=basic&code_challenge=wAYGGEPHpGhaG1gZTmyJ8M1Ly7JlGuoUVWBBVJ4OxTU
```

So I can see that the code parameter has been generated (and in this case given the value `30edd45deb5f42d4bb7bd8413866`. This value should be given to the following code (as `$_GET["code"]`) but it results in a 500 error:

```
<?php    

$code = htmlspecialchars($_GET["code"]);

$code_verifier = 'yyy';

$post_field_array = array(
 'client_id'     => 'xxx',
 'client_secret' => 'zzz',
 'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
 'code'          => $code,
 'redirect_uri'  => 'https://customURL',
 'scope'         => 'basic',
 'code_verifier' => $code_verifier);

// Encode the field values for HTTP.
$post_fields = '';
foreach ($post_field_array as $key => $value)
 $post_fields .= "$key=" . urlencode($value) . '&';
$post_fields = rtrim($post_fields, '&');

// Use cURL to get the JSON response from 23andMe.
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.23andme.com/token/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($post_field_array));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$encoded_json = curl_exec($ch);

$response = json_decode($encoded_json, true);
$access_token = $response['access_token'];

//show 
print_r($encoded_json);
echo $access_token;

?>
```

Now the response with the 500 is:

```
https://api.23andme.com/authorize_check?response_type=code&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FcustomURL&scope=basic&select_profile=false
```

Appreciate any suggestions for troubleshooting.

Comment: I would personally test it first with Curl. If i look at the examples (without knowing this api) i see that in the scope an extra paramter is given (rs3094315). There is a mention of that in the documentation. (https://api.23andme.com/docs/authentication/)  and (https://api.23andme.com/docs/authentication/#scopes)

Comment: thanks - but the scope does not seem to affect the function other than determining the permission to be granted, eg if the scope is set to "scope=rs3094315" the permissions page only requests access to that particular SNP

Comment: Hi - at first glance you are missing a "=" on this line 
$access_token $response['access_token']; It should be $access_token=$response['access_token'];

Comment: thanks for picking that up!  but it seems the problem is earlier in the process - as the code parameter is not being set

Comment: Have you tried with the curl param: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` in order to curl to follow redirects?

Comment: @jp-aulet it appears the second script is not initiated at all

Comment: Is this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269929/curlopt-returntransfer-set-to-true-doesnt-work-on-hosting-server` CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER issue causing your problem?

Comment: Maybe a silly question but it is not clear to me where the `500` error is occurring - on your end, or at `https://api.23andme.com/`?  If it is your end, what do your Apache and PHP logs say?

Comment: @mike32 - there was no accepted solution provided. I'll post the solution I developed

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues around URL encoding; the question does not make clear exactly what your problem is, but I'll suggest making these changes.

In the first code block, you do no URL encoding. This can be a problem if one of your values contains an ampersand or other special character. Use [`http_build_query()`](https://www.php.net/http_build_query) to build a query string safely. In addition, `hash()` can output binary directly so there's no need to use `pack()` on the result, and [you should always exit after a redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665985/php-utilizing-exit-or-die-after-headerlocation). PHP never needs a closing `?>` tag unless there is HTML following (which there shouldn't be.)

```php
<?php

function base64url_encode($data)
{
    $b64 = base64_encode($data);
    if ($b64 === false) {
        return false;
    }
    $url = strtr($b64, '+/', '-_');
    return rtrim($url, '=');
}

$code_verifier = 'yyy';
$hash = hash('sha256', $code_verifier, true);

$query_string_vars = [
    "redirect_uri"   => "https://customURL",
    "response_type"  => "code",
    "client_id"      => "xxx",
    "scope"          => "basic",
    "code_challenge" => base64url_encode($hash),
];

$url = "https://api.23andme.com/authorize/?" . http_build_query($query_string_vars);
header("Location: $url");
exit();
```

In your second code block, you are encoding values using `urlencode()` but this is not necessary, as cURL will automatically encode values passed to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` as an array, or you can use `http_build_query()` again to pass a string. In addition, you use `htmlspecialchars()` on your code value for some reason, which is quite likely to break it.

```php
<?php

$code_verifier = 'yyy';

$post_field_array = [
    'client_id'     => 'xxx',
    'client_secret' => 'zzz',
    'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
    'code'          => $_GET["code"],
    'redirect_uri'  => 'https://customURL',
    'scope'         => 'basic',
    'code_verifier' => $code_verifier
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL            => 'https://api.23andme.com/token/',
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => http_build_query($post_field_array),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    
]);
$json = curl_exec($ch);

$response = json_decode($json, true);
$access_token = $response['access_token'];

//show 
print_r($json);
echo $access_token;
```